# Combine two gulp tasks into one JS file

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have the following two tasks:

```
gulp.task('compress', () => {
    return gulp.src('app/static/angular/**/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('build.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/static'));
});

gulp.task('templates', () => {
    return gulp.src('app/static/angular/**/*.html')
        .pipe(htmlmin())
        .pipe(angularTemplateCache('templates.js', {
            module: 'myApp',
            root: '/static/angular'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/static'))
});
```

And it works fine, but I want them both concatenated into build.js -- how can I combine these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used `merge-stream` to merge the two streams into one output file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');
var angularTemplateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache');
var merge = require('merge-stream');

gulp.task('build', () => {
    var code = gulp.src('app/static/angular/**/*.js');

    var templates = gulp.src('app/static/angular/**/*.html')
        .pipe(htmlmin())
        .pipe(angularTemplateCache({
            module: 'myApp',
            root: '/static/angular'
        }));

    return merge(code, templates)
        .pipe(concat('build.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/static'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the above task mentioned is in separate file say compress.js inside tasks folder

In gulpfile.js you can use below code :

//Include require-dir to include files available in tasks directory

```
var requireDir = require('require-dir');
```

// And Take the tasks directory

```
requireDir('./tasks');
```

Then you can create a build task as below in gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('build', ['compress', 'templates']);
```